# Pandas calculate time difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have date data where I am trying to calculate different in second between successive rows.

My data

```
date
0   2014-05-01 18:47:05
1   2014-05-01 18:47:25
2   2014-05-02 18:47:45
3   2014-05-02 18:48:05
4   2014-05-02 18:48:55
```

Here is what I have try:

```
df['time_diff'] = (df['date']-df['date'].shift()).fillna(0)
df['second'] = df['time_diff'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(1,'s')).astype('int64') % (24*60)
```

But my second column only shows difference between seconds section of the time. Not from entire time.

```
    date                time_diff       second
0   2014-05-01 18:47:05 0 days 00:00:00 0
1   2014-05-01 18:47:25 0 days 00:00:20 20
2   2014-05-02 18:47:45 1 days 00:00:20 20
3   2014-05-02 18:48:05 0 days 00:00:20 20
4   2014-05-02 18:48:55 0 days 00:00:50 50
```

Comment: Yours work too, `df['time_diff'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(1,'s'))` - you don't need `..astype('int64') % (24*60)` and can simply do `df['time_diff'] / np.timedelta64(1,'s')` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks! I honestly got this from another question to solve my problem. I wasnt sure what whole code did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `diff` and `dt.seconds`

```
df.date.diff().dt.seconds
```

---

```
df.assign(seconds=df.date.diff().dt.seconds)

                 date  seconds
0 2014-05-01 18:47:05      NaN
1 2014-05-01 18:47:25     20.0
2 2014-05-02 18:47:45     20.0
3 2014-05-02 18:48:05     20.0
4 2014-05-02 18:48:55     50.0
```