# Error in Pandas calculate time difference in seconds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am trying to extract the time difference (seconds) via Panda frame. I read the data in via text file. But I am getting an error, after I group the data when I apply the diff function.

```
#load data
# this format loads file when there is a 'tab' delimiter in the text file
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n')

# filter data by desired field, traded venues are XLON_SET1, _BATE, _CHIX, _TRQX, XOFF_SET1 etc
dataFil = data[data['VENUE'] == "XLON_SET1"]
# then we need to group them by time-stamp to be sure, to clean up the time-series. This will cause TIME_STAMP and PRICE to become index instead of columns with data
dataFil = dataFil.groupby(['TIME_STAMP', 'PRICE']).sum()
#dataFil = dataFil.groupby(['TIME_STAMP']).sum()

dataFil['date'] = dataFil.index.get_level_values('TIME_STAMP')
dataFil['PRICE'] = dataFil.index.get_level_values('PRICE')
dataFil.head() #or dataFil
```

I get the below data

> QUANTITY  BID ASK MKT_BID MKT_ASK date    PRICE TIME_STAMP    PRICE
>   2018-01-22 08:30:01.306   2.769   3409    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2018-01-22
>   08:30:01.306  2.769 2018-01-22
>   08:30:04.306  2.769   2691    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2018-01-22 08:30:04.306 2.769
>   2018-01-22 08:30:11.306   2.769   2000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2018-01-22
>   08:30:11.306  2.769 2018-01-22
>   08:30:51.065  2.769   572 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2018-01-22 08:30:51.065 2.769
>   2018-01-22 08:31:26.068   2.768   649 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2018-01-22
>   08:31:26.068  2.768

But when I use : (checked this thread : [Pandas calculate time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088123/pandas-calculate-time-difference))

```
df = dataFil
df.assign(seconds=df.date.diff().dt.seconds)
```

I have the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-170-3be32e0aad41> in <module>()
      1 df = dataFil
----> 2 df.assign(seconds=df.date.diff().dt.seconds)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in diff(self, periods)
   1525         diffed : Series
   1526         """
-> 1527         result = algorithms.diff(_values_from_object(self), periods)
   1528         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   1529 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in diff(arr, n, axis)
   1545             out_arr[res_indexer] = result
   1546         else:
-> 1547             out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
   1548 
   1549     if is_timedelta:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: First convert the columns to datetime using pd.to_datetime. currently it's treated as a string type.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I used the following : pd.to_datetime(dataFil['date']) #, format='%Y-%b-%d:%H:%M:%S.%f'
df = dataFil
df.assign(seconds=df.date.diff().dt.seconds)
df

Comment: then I get the error :  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in diff(arr, n, axis)
   1545             out_arr[res_indexer] = result
   1546         else:
-> 1547             out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
   1548 
   1549     if is_timedelta:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Are you assigning it back to the dataframe? df['col']=pd.to_datetime(df['col'])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need convert column `date` to `datetime`s - best in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n', paarse_dates=['TIME_STAMP'])
```

Or convert column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.assign(seconds=pd.to_datetime(df.date).diff().dt.seconds)
```

Comment: It working? I try copy data from question, but failed :(

Comment: this seems to work : df = dataFil

df.assign(seconds=pd.to_datetime(df.date).diff(1).dt.seconds).head()

Comment: *** but ***, crazily, when I reload df again, the 'seconds' column disappears....df = df.assign(seconds=pd.to_datetime(df.date).diff(1).dt.seconds).head() .... this is the answer!!!